# Get access to product advertising api as a developer when you have "coming soon" website

Tags: amazon-product-api, amazon-advertising-api

I want to get credentials to use the Amazon product api for a project im working on, and to do that I need to open an Associates account.

When opening associates account they asked for a link, so I created a coming soon website in wix and gave this link.

After opening the Associates account I went to sign for product advertising api, but I can't sign up cause they say I need my application to be approved, and to get approved I understood I need to be accepted into the Associates Program.

To be accepted into the Associates Program I think I need to put link on my site and make a purchase from one of the product links in my site? not clear how that actually works...

some blog posts said they create some content on their site, which is fake, cant I just tell Amazon I need the api access so I can build my website and its not relevant before?

Comment: Just metooing this. It seems that Amazon does not want developers accessing the Product API, yet it is clear many developers are.

Answer (score -1):

### TLDR: No Shortcut

Solution with min effort:

i faced similar problem, i was told by a sr dev that, we need to create a sample wordpress site using your hosting service's cpanel or other, where we can use astra theme as it looks good, and write around 25 posts with chatgpt which is related to the content you put in associate signup form. it should align with claim you made.

then re apply for api access, but before that submit to google and wait for 2 days, there is high chance that even google adsense may approve . because 25 seems to be magical number many ad providers think the website has good content.

after we get the approval, change whole website as per your wish.

chatgpt link : https://chat.openai.com/auth/login
wordpress quick install: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-wordpress-in-cpanel